# How to get and deal with Chrome URL with javascript (Trying to develop a Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url

I am new to javascript and would like to develop a Chrome extension. I would like to first get the current URL, then check whether or not it is valid.

Also, I still have no idea which event listener should be added.

I'll appreciate any help.

```
function isValidUrl(){
  init();
  check();

  var url;
  function init(){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},function(tabs){
     url = tabs[0].url;
   });
    document.getElementById(“URL”).innerHTML=url;
  }

  function check(){
    if(url.substr(0,7)==='http://'||url.substr(0,8)==='https://'){
      document.getElementById(“display”).innerHTML=“the url is valid”;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(“display”).innerHTML=“the url is invalid”;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener(“load”, isValidUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.location` and `window.location` provide a great way to access and manipulate the current URL, and you don't have to get permission from Chrome to use it in your extension. Look into `document.location.href, document.location.search, document.location.hostname,` etc.